# MongoDB Query advice for weighted randomized aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, database

By far I have encountered ways for selecting random documents but my problem is a bit more of a pickle.So here goes

I have a collection which contains say a **1000+** documents (products)
say  each document has a more or less generic format of .Say for simplicity it is

```
{"_id":{},"name":"Product1","groupid":5}
```

The groupid is a number say between 1 to 20 denoting the product belongs to that group.

Now if my query **input** is something like an array of {groupid->weight} for eg **{[{"2":4},{"7":6}]}** and say another parameter **n(=10 say)** Then I need to be able to pick **4 random documents** that belong to groupid 2 and **6 random documents** that belong to groupid 7.

The only solution i can think of is to run 'm' subqueries where m is the array length in the query input.
How do I accomplish this an efficient manner in MongoDB using probably a Mapreduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picking up `n` random documents for each group.

- Group the records by the `groupid` field. Emit the `groupid` as `key`
  and the `record` as `value`.
- For each group pick `n` random documents from the `values` array.

Let,

`var parameter = {"5":1,"6":2};` //groupid->weight, keep it as an Object.

be the input to the map reduce functions.

The `map` function, emit only those group ids which we have provided as the `parameter`.

```
var map = function map(){
if(parameter.hasOwnProperty(this.groupid)){
   emit(this.groupid,this);
 }
}
```

The `reduce` function, for each group, get random records based on the `parameter` object in `scope`.

```
var reduce = function(key,values){
    var length = values.length;
    var docs = [];
    var added = [];
    var i= 1;
    while(i<=parameter[key]){
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*length);
        if(added.indexOf(index) == -1){
         docs.push(values[index]);
         added.push(index);
         i++;
        }
        else{
            i--;
        }
    }
    return {result:docs};
}
```

Invoking map reduce on the collection, by passing the `parameter` object in scope.

```
db.collection.mapReduce(map,
               reduce,
              {out: "sam",
               scope:{"parameter":{"5":1,"6":2,"n":10}}})
```

To get the dumped output:

```
db.sam.find({},{"_id":0,"value.result":1}).pretty()
```

When you bring the parameter `n` into picture, you need to specify the number of documents for each group as a ratio, or else that parameter is not necessary at all.